# issues with calling a superclass's method and adding the returned value to an array

Tags: python

When I try to enter the code below, I get `[None, None]` printed on the console rather than the expected `[3, 3]` and was wondering what would help to fix this.

```
class Blah(object):
    def track(self,dot):
      self.dot = dot


class Second(Blah):
  def __init__(self,arg):
    self.blocky = []
      x = 0
       while x < 2:
         self.blocky.append(Blah.track(self,arg))
          x += 1

bleh = Second(3)
print bleh.blocky
```

Comment: Just use `self.blocky.append(arg)`

Answer (score 1):

Among other more minor issues, your `track` method doesn't return anything, so you're passing the returned value of a function that returns nothing (`None` in other words) into that list.

The following worked for me:

```
class Blah(object):
    def track(self, dot):
      self.dot = dot
      return self.dot


class Second(Blah):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.blocky = []
        x = 0
        while x < 2:
            self.blocky.append(self.track(arg))
            x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`Blah.track` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None`.

You could fix this by doing:

```
class Blah(object):
  def track(self, dot):
    self.dot = dot
    return dot
```

Also, you're calling `Blah.track(self, dot)` when you could just be calling `self.track(dot)`, since `self` is a `Second`, which is a subclass of `Blah`.

That might look like this:

```
class Second(Blah):
  def __init__(self,arg):
    self.blocky = []
    x = 0
    while x < 2:
       self.blocky.append(self.track(arg))
       x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The track method isn't returning anything. Perhaps you meant this?

```
def track(self, dot):
    self.dot = dot
    return dot
```

Also, since Second inherits from Blah you can replace

```
Blah.track(self, arg)
```

with

```
self.track(arg)
```